# Merge column in Markdown

Tags: markdown, readme

How can I merge column in markdown for a single value. 
What I want is something like

[image]

What I am able to get is

| Experiment | TestType | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Experiment 1 | TestType1 | 98 |
| Experiment 1 | TestType2 | 73 |
| Experiment 2 | TestType1 | 93 |
| Experiment 3 | TestType2 | 79 |

I couldn't find anything good. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: So my ultimate goal was to display in given format. It turns out markdown is not capable of that. But ultimately I'm displaying it on browser which is able to parse HTML, so HTML solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to use your markdown.

If `HTML` elements are supported you can add a `<table>` to your markdown and change the `colspan` or `rowspan` as prefered. One example could look like this:

```css
/* just for a better overview */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Experiment</th>
            <th>TestType</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan=2>Experiment 1</td>
            <td>TestType1</td>
            <td>98</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TestType2</td>
            <td>73</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Experiment 2</td>
            <td>TestType1</td>
            <td>93</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Experiment 3</td>
            <td>TestType2</td>
            <td>79</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But if you want to change the readme in Github e.g. thats not possible (see [this specification](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-)).

Comment: They said Markdown not HTML .

Comment: @Mehdi but since the answer is accepted I would recommend to change the question.